# I want to control dynamic subMenu auto column in wpf. if 5 row auto break 1 column. how?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, submenu

I want to control dynamic subMenu auto column in wpf. if 5 row auto break 1 column. how?
I think if control grid in code bihinde but i dont' know. can you help me.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: content my question in below. please help me